# \Magento\Backend\Model\Session Clear: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sessions, checkoutsession

In Magento, we could use as `$this->_getSession()->clear();`

However, in
magento 2 if we use the same thing it throws exception as

> Invalid method Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Interceptor::clear

Is there any way to do this in Magento 2?

I tried to search about this but could not find anything relevant.

Please, can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the method you are looking for in Magento 2 is destroy().

Take a look at the following class [Magento\Backend\Model\Session](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9c14af7a97bcf338662de365d2613c7ca9dbf8c6/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Message/Session.php) it extends [\Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Session/SessionManager.php) which has two methods that you would find helpful.

- **clearStorage()** which clears all the stored data from the session and still keeps the session active
- **destroy()** which ends a session

The `destroy()` method allows you to carry out a combination of 2 actions, ***Clear Storage and or end session***, whereas the `clearStorage()` method only clears the storage

Answer (score 3):

For frontend,

```
protected $session;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session
) {
    $this->session = $session;
}
```

**//Unset all session data front**

```
$this->session->clearStorage();

/* Destroy/end session front */
/* if you want to destroy specific session pass array value 
* otherwise null
*/

$this->session->destroy(array $options = null);
```

**`For Backend`**

```
protected $adminSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $adminSession
) {
    $this->adminSession = $adminSession;
}
```

**//Unset all admin session data**

```
$this->adminSession->clearStorage();

//Destroy/end admin session
/* if you want to destroy specific session pass array value 
* otherwise null
*/

$this->adminSession->destroy(array $options = null);
```